# Compare 3 digit dot separated number with >3 digit and alphanumeric in Perl

Tags: perl

Can anybody help to perform the below operation in Perl?

1. Read a set of numbers or chars from a file (ex. 2021.2.3.0 / 2.8.1 / 2021.3.1_alpha ).
2. Compare it with number 2.4.0. (always the same number) if greater or smaller.
3. Ex: (2.4.0 < 2021.2.3.0) --> this is false. so do nothing.
4. if (2.4.0 > 2.3.0) --> True - So do some operation.
5. For 3 digit numbers with dot separated we can do this. (actually we are doing).
6. But how to compare for digits and alpha numeric which has more that 3 digits.

Here i need to always compare with 2.4.0. Can any one guide me on how to do this in Perl?

My existing code is below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path_ice = $ARGV[0];
my $filename = ($#ARGV == 0) ?  $ARGV[0]."\\medc17_tools.ini" : $ARGV[1];
my $flag = 0;
my $buld_ver = "";
my @buld_very = "";
my $status = 55;
if (open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename))
 {
 while (my $line = <$fh>)
   {
   chomp $line;
   if($line=~m/^PRJ_BUILD_NAME=mdgb/) {$flag = 1;}
   if($line=~m/^PRJ_BUILD_VERSION=/)
     {
     @buld_very = split('=',$line);
     $buld_ver = substr($buld_very[1], 0, 5);
     $buld_ver =~ tr/.//d;
     if ($buld_ver < 240 ) {$status = 44;}
     last;
     }
   }
} 
else {
      warn "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    }
if ($flag == 1)
{
exit(1);
}
else
   {
   exit(0);
    }
```

Here we are converting dot separated to whole number and comparing. It works well for 3 digit values. But don't know how to handle for alphanumeric and >3 digit dot separated numbers.

Any help?

Comment: "_how to compare for digits and alpha numeric_" -- well, how do you compare them? What is the criterion for comparing `2.4.0` and `2021.3.1_alpha`?  I doubt that it's just `2 < 2021` ?  Then, is that other format always N.N....alpha ?

Comment: Let me very clear on this: My old tool version is 2.4.0. Latest tool version can be alpha numeric or other. Ex: as said above 2021.2.3.0 or 2021.3.1_alpha. For some task i need to enable other operation when the tool version selected is lesser than 2.4.0. Our existing code easily compares 2.4.0 with 1.2.0 or 2.3.0 or 3.3.0. But when it comes to like 2021.2.3.0 or with alpha numeric - we are facing issues..

Comment: Alright.  Can you explain how one compares `2.4.0` with `2021.2.3.0` -- by what criteria? In the question you say that `2.4.0` is larger than `2021.2.3.0` ?  (By saying that `2.4.0 < 2021.2.3.0` is false.)  So, how do you compare them?  Comparing `2.4.0` and `1.2.0` is clear -- but how do these `2021.n.n.n` compare with things like `2.n.n`?  Normally one compares by position w.r.t to the `.` (or `-`), first ones then second ones etc (with some other details).  That's not the case here you say since `2.n.n < 2021.n.n.n` _**is false**_ you say, so how _do_ they compare? That's what I am asking.

Comment: (the question in my comment above was answered in comments below my answer)

Answer (score 5):

For versions that contain both numbers and non-numeric strings one tool is [Sort::Versions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Versions)

```
use Sort::Versions;

my @sorted versions = sort versioncmp qw( 2021.2.3.0  2.8.1  2021.3.1_alpha );
```

In very very old Perls (pre-5.6) use `sort { versioncmp($a, $b) } LIST`

Or compare individually

```
if (versioncmp('2.4.0', '2.4.0_a') == -1) { ... }  # first is "lesser"
```

The criterion is

> ... the two strings are treated as subunits delimited by periods or hyphens. Each subunit can contain any number of groups of digits or non-digits. If digit groups are being compared on both sides, a numeric comparison is used, otherwise a ASCII ordering is used. A group or subgroup with more units will win if all comparisons are equal. A period binds digit groups together more tightly than a hyphen.

---

The first example above (the sort), when printed produces

```
2.8.1
2021.2.3.0
2021.3.1_alpha
```

But a bulleted example in the questions says

> Ex: (2.4.0 < 2021.2.3.0) --> this is false. so do nothing.

It has been clarified in comments that in a version string like `2021.2.3.0` that leading `2021` is a year; the rest of the string is then compared to a conventional format like `2.4.0`.

*My additional assumptions*: later year wins, regardless of the rest, and if only one version has a year then that one is newer.

A simple sub suffices

```
use Sort::Versions qw(versioncmp);   # imported by default, too

sub cmp_versions {
    my ($v1, $v2) = @_; 
    #croak "Usage: ", (caller(0))[3], " version-string version-string" 
    #   if not $v1 or not $v2;

    # Extract and collect years (need 'undef' when no year)
    my @years = map { /^([0-9]{4})\./ // undef } $v1, $v2;

    # Larger year wins; if same, or both absent, compare versions
    if ($years[0] and $years[1]) { 
        return $years[0] <=> $years[1] || versioncmp($v1, $v2)
    }   
    elsif ($years[0]) { return  1 } 
    elsif ($years[1]) { return -1 } 
    else              { versioncmp($v1, $v2) }     
}
```

A test program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

#sub cmp_versions { ... }    # From above

my ($v1, $v2) = @ARGV;
$v1 //= '2021.2.0';
$v2 //= '2021.2.0_b';  #--> -1 (the first one considered earlier)

say cmp_versions($v1, $v2);
```

If sorting versions the same can be used

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Sort::Versions;

sub sort_versions {    
    return sort {
        my $ya = $a =~ /^([0-9]{4})\./;
        my $yb = $b =~ /^([0-9]{4})\./;
    
        if ($ya and $yb) {
            $ya <=> $yb || versioncmp($a, $b)
        }
        elsif ($ya) {  1 }
        elsif ($yb) { -1 }
        else        { versioncmp($a, $b) }
    }
    @_;
}

my @versions = qw(2.4.0 2021.2 2.4.0.0 2022.1.1 2021.2_a 2.6);

say for sort_versions( @versions );
```

Output

```
2.4.0
2.4.0.0
2.6
2021.2
2021.2_a
2022.1.1
```

This conforms to the described or mentioned  criteria, some clarified in comments.

As for yet other possible (unstated) details --
a library can only do so much to make sense of any given versioning scheme, or to guess the intended comparison criteria.  For very particular criteria the strings to compare may need to first be preprocessed into a more conventional scheme, or the "tricky" ones can be compared by hand.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Here in our code we always wants to check or compare with the number 2.4.0 is greater or equal. If only lesser we enable other operation for the task. The right hand side can be as i said before. 2021.2.3.0 is a tool version which we need to compare with older tool version 2.4.0

Comment: Let me very clear on this: My old tool version is 2.4.0. Latest tool version can be alpha numeric or other. Ex: as said above 2021.2.3.0 or 2021.3.1_alpha. For some task i need to enable other operation when the tool version selected is lesser than 2.4.0. Our existing code easily compares 2.4.0 with 1.2.0 or 2.3.0 or 3.3.0. But when it comes to like 2021.2.3.0 or with alpha numeric - we are facing issues..

Comment: We used to read the current version from other file and always compare it with 2.4.0.. like  if ($buld_ver < 240 ) {$status = 44;} In this code "buld_ver" will be taken from other file. it can be 2021.2.3.0 or 2021.3.1_alpha or 1.3.0

Comment: Alright, that's about how they are read into the program, that's fine.  The unclear part is how to compare different things like `2.4.0` and `2021.2.3.0`, since you say that it's not the usual `2` vs `2021` etc  (if it were then `2.4.0 < 2021.2.3.0` but the question says that that is false).

Comment: Ok. Our old tools has only 3 digit version number like 1.2.0 / 2.3.0 / 3.3.0. But recently this was updated and now we appended the year with the tool version... like 2019.3.3.0 or 2021.3.1.3 etc..

Comment: @VijayanandBalu Ah, so that _is_ the year.  But so is what follows the year the version -- like the version `2021.3.1.3` is `3.1.3` (of 2021) and so it is "greater" (later) than `2.4.0`? If that's the case then it's easy to include this year-tagged versions in any comparison.  (Bit confirm please -- or correct me if things are different -- before I edit the the answer.)

Comment: exactly..  now we always use the digit 2.4.0 and compare this with the version available in other file. The version which we need to compare can have alphanumeric also...My suggestion would be 2.4.0 will be always older (greater) then the version which starts with year. Any idea how can i modify the existing code which i posted.

Comment: @VijayanandBalu Posted a simple take on it, review.  I can't fully test right now, but this works as it stands and it should be feasible to modify as needed. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: @VijayanandBalu How did this go? I've updated to everything you clarified.